# asp.net failed to remember username and password after logging out

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm using asp.net loggin control in VS2013, and I'm using asp membership

the code for login is

```
 <asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server" BackColor="#EFF3FB" BorderColor="#B5C7DE" BorderPadding="2" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="0.8em" ForeColor="#333333" Height="186px" Width="438px" RememberMeSet="True" EnableViewState="true">
        <InstructionTextStyle Font-Italic="True" ForeColor="Black" />
        <LoginButtonStyle BackColor="White" BorderColor="#507CD1" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="0.8em" ForeColor="#284E98" />
        <TextBoxStyle Font-Size="0.8em" />
        <TitleTextStyle BackColor="#1B4D82" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="0.9em" ForeColor="White" />
    </asp:Login>
```

the code behind my login page is:

```
  Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Dim username As String = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name

       If Not username = Nothing And User.Identity.IsAuthenticated = True Then

            Server.Transfer("Home1.aspx")


      End If


     End Sub
```

The authentication is my web.config is

```
  <authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH" loginUrl="abc/def/login.aspx" defaultUrl="abc/def/login.aspx" timeout="60" cookieless="UseCookies"/>   
  </authentication>
```

i also found something at 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/friis/archive/2010/08/18/remember-me-checkbox-does-not-work-with-forms-authentication.aspx

and I added this to my loggin page

```
  Protected Sub OnLoggedIn(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    If Login1.RememberMeSet = True Then

        'clear any other tickets that are already in the response
        Response.Cookies.Clear()
        'set the new expiry date - to thirty days from now
        Dim expiryDate As DateTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30)
        'create a new forms auth ticket
        Dim ticket As FormsAuthenticationTicket = New FormsAuthenticationTicket(2,            Login1.UserName, DateTime.Now, expiryDate, True, String.Empty)
        'encrypt the ticket
        Dim encryptedTicket As String = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket)
        'create a new authentication cookie - and set its expiration date
        Dim authenticationCookie As HttpCookie = New HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket)
        authenticationCookie.Expires = ticket.Expiration
        'add the cookie to the response.
        Response.Cookies.Add(authenticationCookie)
    End If
End Sub
```

still, the username and password didn't get saved after I clicked logged out.

I wonder how I can fix this? Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Is your logout function calling FormsAuthentication.SignOut() by any chance?

Comment: no, I didn't have any function for the log out. I just used asp login status

Comment: And cookies are enabled in your test?

Comment: yes, i added cookieless="UseCookies" in web config

Comment: It may be that asp.net login control has the ticket creation wired in and is creating a "good for one session" authentication ticket and is overwriting your ticket. Use the f12 debugger tool and check the expiration date of the ASPXFORMSAUTH. It should be  30 days out?

Comment: Also, I wonder if this is a session time out issue in that you have a valid authentication ticket but you have abandoned the session and are asked to log in again.

Comment: You are right, i should set timeout to be 43200. Still, how should I deal with the session time out issue?

Comment: You could override the Session_Start() in global.asax with the same logic as in your OnLoggedIn  but with User.Identity.IsAuthenticated and one extra step, Authenticate the user....If the user has a valid ticket then re-authenticate and make sure that their credentials are still valid. Next, extend the ticket another x amount of time and redirect the user to a home page. You might beforced to encrypt the user's password in the userdata field of the ticket if you are going to support re-authentication.